# How to do time_to_minute in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, time

How to make time to time_to_minute unit? (same like time_to_sec)

```
mysql> select time_to_min('00:00:1');
mysql> select time_to_minute('00:00:1');
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('00:00:1') / 60
```

Answer (score 9):

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
-> 128885
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: This is not good if you desire to have seconds part counted, like 00:02:30 will return 2 instead of 2.5