# MySQL: Convert a string representation of hh mm into actually minutes

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my database where time has been stored in the format hh mm

```
e.g. 03 00 = 3 hours 
e.g. 03 15 = 3 hours 15 minutes
```

How can I convert this into actual minutes

```
e.g. 03 00 = 180 minutes
e.g. 03 15 = 195 minutes
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918923/how-to-do-time-to-minute-in-mysql

Comment: Split the string, multiply the first number by 60, add it to the second number.

Comment: You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the two parts of the string.

Comment: Cool, nice solution. Let me give it a go.

Comment: Anyone interested in the answer to this, with @Barmar help I was able to work it up this:

    UPDATE exp_channel_data
 SET field_id_2 = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_id_2, ' ', 1) * 60) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_id_2, ' ', -1)

Comment: For anyone interested in an answer using the method I posted: SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(timestuff.formattedtime) / 60
FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT("00:", REPLACE(timefield, " ", ":")) as formattedtime
  FROM WhateverTableStoresThisInfo
) as timestuff