# SQL Convert from Type time to Minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, time, types

in my database I have the running time of a movie as type: time.

How do I select the values in minutes as an integer?

Thank you!

Comment: Try the answer to [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918923/how-to-do-time-to-minute-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do time\_to\_minute in Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918923/how-to-do-time-to-minute-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT f.Titel, ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(Laufzeit)/60) 
FROM film f 
WHERE f.Erscheinungsjahr >= 1980 ORDER BY f.Titel ASC
```

Comment: my Problem here is that the minutes are displayed with 4 decimal places..

Comment: ok, wow sorry I was dumb. It worked. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert it this way:

```
select (datediff(second,0,[timeValue])/60) as [TimeinMinutes]
```

This is a SQL Server statement.

Below is an example to try out for SQL Server:

```
create table #tbl1 (
    [RunningTime] time
);

insert into #tbl1 ([RunningTime])
values
    ('10:53')
;

select
    [RunningTime]
    ,datediff(second,0,[RunningTime]) as [RunningTimeInSeconds]
    ,(datediff(second,0,[RunningTime])/60) as [RunningTimeInMinutes]
from #tbl1
;

drop table #tbl1;
```

Comment: somehow it doesn't seem to like the [ ] here

Comment: @NicoleW. - the **[timeValue]** needs to be replaced with the actual value you need.

Comment: as soon as I insert my cellname I get the error: 1582 incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: Thats my query: SELECT f.Titel,  datediff(second,0,Laufzeit)/60
 FROM  film f WHERE f.Erscheinungsjahr >= 1980  ORDER BY f.Titel ASC

Comment: @NicoleW. are you executing this query using SQL Server or using another version of SQL? This should work if you're using SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: @NicoleW. if you're using mysql then the **TIME_TO_SEC** function should be able to convert this for you. The example that Starv00 gave should work.