# Convert t\time in to minutes in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`timetaken`))) as tt FROM user_data where completed_stage='1'
```

When I run this query this is how I will get result

```
00:05:04.0000
```

I want to convert that whole time in to minutes

Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Go through this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918923/how-to-do-time-to-minute-in-mysql]

Comment: you mean I just need to add /60 ?

Comment: yes try this one `select TIME_TO_SEC(timetaken) / 60 as tt from user_data where completed_stage='1'`

Comment: its depend on you if you want average minutes then you can use AVG function.

Comment: yes I want avg minutes

Comment: use this `select AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(timetaken) / 60) as tt from user_data where completed_stage='1'`

Comment: when I run that this is result I am getting 5.06666667

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163624/discussion-between-user200-and-saddam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your result as per your requirement please use this query.

```
select ROUND(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(timetaken) / 60)) as tt from user_data where completed_stage='1'
```